# Laravel domain routing in production and dev

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a working Laravel 5.2 project using sub-domain routing that I run locally (homestead) and in production (forge configured with wildcard subdomain routing on AWS).  My local project has a host file entry for admin.project.app and successfully routes to admin.project.**app** while my production version routes to admin.project.**com**.

My local .env file has the variable APP_ENV=local while my .env on forge has the variable APP_ENV=production.  So far, so good.

The problem I am having is that I would expect Laravel to resolve the domain based on the fact that I am running locally (with the extension of .app) or in production (with the extension of .com) using this type of wildcard routing rule:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.project.*'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

});
```

The problem I am having is that either Laravel, Ngnix, AWS, or Forge is requiring me to explicitly route like this, which seems completely redundant:

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
    Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.project.app'], function()
    {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

    });
}else{
    Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.project.com'], function()
    {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

    });

}
```

Or maybe my expectations are just wrong ;)  Any pointers as to what I may be doing wrong are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

The really easy solution would be to use a ternary operator to determine the TLD and use that in the group's `domain` attribute:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.project.' . ((env('APP_ENV') == 'production') ? 'com' : 'app')], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Avoiding duplication of code and adding additional environment variables.

Comment: I like this, and tried it, but apparently Laravel doesn't like assembling the domain attribute on the fly like this.  I can't believe I have to hack something together in Laravel to account for TLD.  Yuk.

Comment: @Gunnar This approach works, I've used it myself in the past, but there was a small problem with the code in the answer. I've updated it to wrap the TLD expression in parentheses, otherwise the string concatenation doesn't work properly, because arithmetic operators such as `.` [have precedence](http://bit.ly/1BPqFi3) over ternary operators `?` and `:`, so when evaluated it tried to concatenate the string with the result of the condition which is `true` or `false`, not the result of the expression which is `com` or `app`.

Answer (score 2):

Does the same thing happen with a route param `{}` instead of `*`?  I am not sure that laravel routing supports *:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.project.{tld}'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Or what if you just used the domain as an ENV variable?  In your env file locally, add:

`APP_DOMAIN=admin.project.app`

Then in the route file:

```
Route::group(['domain' => env("APP_DOMAIN","admin.project.com")],function(){

});
```

Comment: The second solution is a good one. The first however will most certainly create confusion when routes have their own parameters. Because if you have a route definition like this `Route::get('user/{name}', 'UsersController@show');`, the action method will receive two parameters `show($tld, $name)`, so all route actions having parameters of their own will end up needing to add the extra `$tld` parameter.